# How do I place an image at certain position of a web page?

Tags: html, css

I want to position an image (basically a logo) at the bottom right side of my page. I am trying to do it using TOP and LEFT. However, that doesn't have any effect. Moreover, I don't want to do absolute positioning but a relative positioning.

P.S: I know you can align towards the right by using **align=right**. But, is there also something to align to the bottom right?

```
 <body style="height: 100vh; width: 100vw" background="images/background.jpg">
    .........
    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" style="TOP:235px;LEFT:270px;">
 </body>
```

Comment: Do you want it fixed or just at the very bottom right?

Comment: I want it to be at very bottom right.

Comment: Relative positioning will only move the element in relation to it's **current** position. To fix it in relation to the *viewport* use **fixed** positioning. So, as it stands right now...you CAN'T.

Comment: OK. Can you give some simple example?

Comment: `<img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" style="bottom: 0; right: 0; position: fixed">`

Comment: Vow @MuhammadUsman, that worked like a charm. Than you very much :)! Maybe put it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Try to use img { position:fixed; right:0; bottom:0; }

Comment: @pythonic: Knowledge purpose know about The CSS POSITIONS carefully: http://learnlayout.com/position.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relative positioning will only move the element in relation to it's **current position** as defined by the current layout.

To fix it in relation to the *viewport* use **fixed** positioning

```css
#ImSticky {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<img id="ImSticky" src="http://www.fillmurray.com/140/100" />
```

**Note:**

This element will stay where it is regardless of the amount of content on the page. It won't move up or down when you scroll. Accordingly, this may not be precisely what you **actually** require.

**Note 2:**

Positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: I see. But that seems to be generic. What If I want to put a specific image at the bottom right.

Comment: Then just specify with a selector.

Comment: It is generic. If you want a specific image, give it an ID and use that.

Comment: OK. Since I'm very new to HTML, CSS, can you help me a bit, and show the example with image ID?

Comment: Very cool @Paulie_D. I am loving this HTML and CSS stuff. Its very intriguing :).

Answer (score 1):

> Hey try this, it has worked for me it will display your logo at right
>   bottom

```
<style type="text/css">
  .log
  {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;bottom:0;
  }

</style>
<div class="log">
  <img alt="mylogo" src="c1.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position: fixed` that will place an element relative to the viewport.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.logo {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">
 </body>
```

Comment: **To the downvoter:** Can you justify your downvote?